# Why are all my HDRIs displaying distorted?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, hdri

Here's an image of the distortion. [image: Distorted HDRI] And here are my shader settings [image: Shader settings]
I'm just a beginner in Blender, and at first my HDRIs (from HDRI Haven) were working fine, but now they all display distorted as shown. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the texture coordinates node. Delete the vector mapping node. Delete the image texture node.

Add an Environment Texture Node, use the image in it and set it to Equirectangular.

[image]

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks, Susu!